# What's the next awesome number after π?

Tags: discussion, badges, fun

Today, I was foolish enough to use the rollback button. Now on stack overflow I no longer have 3 silver badges and 14 bronze badges. My joy in opening the website every day in a pinned tab in Chrome is severely diminished now. FML

I know that badges once given can't be taken away. What's the next awesome number I should aim for, then?

I *could* get 3 gold badges and 11 silver badges, which would get me •3 •14 •15 -- but that's nearly impossible to do without getting more bronze badges.

Comment: •6 •66 could be doable...

Comment: Be rational, get real.

Comment: @Balus: You mean •22 •7? :/

Comment: a c-ish answer would be: pi++;

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net ?

Comment: **It's NOT Friday.**

Comment: @kip: We have a **mathoverflow**?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Table of selected mathematical constants at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_constant#Table_of_selected_mathematical_constants):

```
 Symbol | Value                                         | Name
--------+-----------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------
 0      | = 0                                           | Zero
 1      | = 1                                           | One, Unity
 i      | = \sqrt{-1}                                   | Imaginary unit
 π      | ≈ 3.14159 26535 89793 23846 26433 83279 50288 | Pi, Archimedes' constant
 e      | ≈ 2.71828 18284 59045 23536 02874 71352 66249 | Napier's constant, or Euler's number
 √2     | ≈ 1.41421 35623 73095 04880 16887 24209 69807 | Pythagoras' constant, square root of 2
 √3     | ≈ 1.73205 08075 68877 29352 74463 41505 87236 | Theodorus' constant, square root of 3
 √5     | ≈ 2.23606 79774 99789 69640 91736 68731 27623 | square root of 5
 γ      | ≈ 0.57721 56649 01532 86060 65120 90082 40243 | Euler-Mascheroni constant
 φ      | ≈ 1.61803 39887 49894 84820 45868 34365 63811 | Golden ratio
 ρ      | ≈ 1.32471 79572 44746 02596 09088 54478 09734 | Plastic constant
 β*     | ≈ 0.70258                                     | Embree-Trefethen constant
 δ      | ≈ 4.66920 16091 02990 67185 32038 20466 20161 | Feigenbaum constant
 α      | ≈ 2.50290 78750 95892 82228 39028 73218 21578 | Feigenbaum constant
 C2     | ≈ 0.66016 18158 46869 57392 78121 10014 55577 | Twin prime constant
 M1     | ≈ 0.26149 72128 47642 78375 54268 38608 69585 | Meissel-Mertens constant
 B2     | ≈ 1.90216 05823                               | Brun's constant for twin primes
 B4     | ≈ 0.87058 83800                               | Brun's constant for prime quadruplets
 Λ      | ≥ –2.7 • 10−9                                 | de Bruijn-Newman constant
 K      | ≈ 0.91596 55941 77219 01505 46035 14932 38411 | Catalan's constant
 K      | ≈ 0.76422 36535 89220 66299 06987 31250 09232 | Landau-Ramanujan constant
 K      | ≈ 1.13198 824                                 | Viswanath's constant
 B´L    | = 1                                           | Legendre's constant
 μ      | ≈ 1.45136 92348 83381 05028 39684 85892 02744 | Ramanujan-Soldner constant
 EB     | ≈ 1.60669 51524 15291 76378 33015 23190 92458 | Erdős–Borwein constant
 β      | ≈ 0.28016 94990 23869 13303                   | Bernstein's constant
 λ      | ≈ 0.30366 30028 98732 65859 74481 21901 55623 | Gauss-Kuzmin-Wirsing constant
 σ      | ≈ 0.35323 63718 54995 98454                   | Hafner-Sarnak-McCurley constant
 λ,μ    | ≈ 0.62432 99885 43550 87099 29363 83100 83724 | Golomb–Dickman constant
 Λ      | ≈ 1.09868 58055                               | Lengyel's constant
 ζ(3)   | ≈ 1.20205 69031 59594 28539 97381 61511 44999 | Apéry's constant
 θ      | ≈ 1.30637 78838 63080 69046 86144 92602 60571 | Mills' constant
 K      | ≈ 2.58498 17595 79253 21706 58935 87383 17116 | Sierpiński's constant
 F      | ≈ 2.80777 02420 28519 36522 15011 86557 77293 | Fransén-Robinson constant
 L      | ≈ 0.5                                         | Landau's constant
 P2     | ≈ 2.29558 71493 92638 07403 42980 49189 49039 | Parabolic constant
 Ω      | ≈ 0.56714 32904 09783 87299 99686 62210 35555 | Omega constant
```

Take your pick.

Personally I don't care about special numbers like *pi*, but what would have been cool is to have the badge numbers to be exactly the same as the reputation points. So for example, if I had a reputation of 12345, then I'd like at the moment have 1 gold, 23 silver and 45 bronze (and quickly take a screen).

Comment: How would you do it with 2207 rep?

Comment: @mmyers: Who says that it stays 2207 all the time? Make it thrilling!

Comment: On StackOverflow he needs •6 •47 •60 and has •4 •36 •67 so he's close enough...

Comment: Or get one more gold at meta and gain 2315 rep :P The question is, which gold is easy to earn after fanatic? Electorate?

Comment: Technically, Electorate is the generally easiest gold to acquire of them all (least amount of days, and no luck involved).

Answer (score 13):

Obviously, the most awesome course of action would be to get a badge count of *i*. I don't know how you will accomplish this, but I guarantee you that once you do, you'll be the envy of everyone.

Comment: A 1 looks a bit like an i

Comment: @Charles, so then it's just a job of picking the right browser font.

Answer (score 5):

Well [e](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) is less than π, so that wouldn't work. What about [Avogadro's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avogadro_constant), 6.02e23:

•6 •02 •23

Except it wouldn't display the silver badges with the leading zero of course

Comment: Then you should strive to get 602 silver and 23 bronze.

Comment: I somehow missed your answer...

Comment: 60 silver and 223 bronze is possible, but you'll be hard-pressed to keep from getting at least one gold.

Answer (score 3):

Goal: •31 •415 •9265

Get cracking.  You'll never achieve that by messing about on MSO.

Comment: Sadly, Jon Skeet can't ever do this because he already has *696* silver badges.

Comment: This looks like a joke...except that Jon Skeet has actually exceeded both of the scores for both Gold and Silver.  The Bronze, however, he is nowhere near.  He would have to post a lot more consistently mediocre answers to achieve this.

Comment: I Simulskeeted.

Comment: 926 bronzes is more realistic.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best option would be to go to area51 and get behind [the mathematics proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3355/mathematics). You can then try to accomplish the same thing there :-)

Answer (score 1):

If this is something that you are severely and completely distressed about (despondent, even), you could email team@stackoverflow.com, and request that they obliterate whichever badge it is that offends you so.

Of course, they're quite busy, so this would be ridiculous. But the option is still there.

Comment: That would be _cheating_!

Comment: Not if there was an "annoying the SO team about dumb stuff" **ANTI** badge.

Answer (score 1):

•13 •37 Perhaps? If you like that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

•4 •20

<sup><sub>I know nothing, I swear.</sub></sup>

Comment: Possibly the wrong audience for this answer. lol

Comment: you don't think people at the site with the rainbow pony avatars know anything about marih juh wanna?

Answer (score 1):

## [e](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29)

Comment: A.K.A. 2.71828182845904523536… and lim n→∞ (1+1/n)^n

Comment: Of course, you'd have to get •27 •18 •28...

Comment: •2 •71 •82 or even •2 •71 •828 might be a little more likely.

Comment: For some reason I misread and thought that he already had 3 golden badges, but yea, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

I once hoped I could get my user ID number: •5 •27 •38

But alas, I got one too many bronze badges on SO. And I only needed one more gold and 5 more silvers to do it. Woe is me.

You could still do it though: •1 •39 •92

Get crackin' on some moderately good answers!